# How to remove Post and Poll from Salesforce Case Chatter tab in Lighthing Experience?

Tags: lightning-experience, case, service-console

Firstly, I don't understand why Salesforce would think that people want to use Chatter in cases. Are people doing this these days? What possible use or benefit does this offer in the real world? (this is not my primary question, but if there are some facts to support this, I'd love to see them).

My question is, since Chatter appears to be the primary method of working a case, how does one remove the Post and Poll tabs from the Chatter tab on a Case?

[image]

I'm also wanting to know if there's a way to remove these from Service Console was well.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the case page layout on which you're working and remove those actions from `Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions`:

[image]

Then it would be gone:

[image]

Some helpful links:

- [Understand How Actions Work in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_migration_customization/units/lex_migration_customization_actions)
- [Actions in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5)